# Stopping both hyper-v replicas from booting

Tags: hyper-v, replication

Consider the following hyper-v configuration:

host1, running guest1 
host2, running guest2

guest1 replicated using hyper-v replication to host2
guest2 replicated using hyper-v replication to host1

Consider the following outage to host2

host2 goes offline due to sysadmin shutdown of host for planned hardware upgrade
sysadmin team brings guest2 up on host1
services are restored and the business keeps running

Some time passes...
The sysadmin team boots host2
Guests configured to automatically start, such as guest2, boot

There are 2 guest2 instances booted.

Question: Is there a configuration in which guest2 would not boot on host2 when host2 is bought online after an outage during which host1 brought up its replica of guest2

In the scenario above I appreciate that if guest2 had been failed over to host1 before host2 shut down, then when host2 would not have started guest2 when it was bought online, however in an unplanned outage noone would know to fail guest2 over in advance

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing this.  Are you asking about a fail-over configuration?  A configuration where one replica **and only** one replica of a VM boots?  Something else?

Comment: You don't say which version of HyperV, but Live Migration would be one way to migrate the Guest VM to the other host. Of course this isn't always a solution for some enviornments.  For our webserver VMs that are small, we can move them around in 2-3 minutes and they stay online while moving.  Once the migration is complete then the host they were sitting on can be taken down for maintenance.  Obviously this wouldn't work in a hardware failure type scenario as the migration only happens when prompted.  But you wouldn't have 2 copies to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question: Is there a configuration in which guest2 would not boot on host2 when host2 is bought online after an outage during which host1 brought up its replica of guest2?

A: No there isn't.

The easiest thing to do IMO would be to disconnect the previously failed hosts Virtual Switch NIC so that the VM's have no network connectivity. You can then shut down the appropriate VM's and perform a reverse replication.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I suspect its right but will hold out accepting for 24 hrs or so.